# Opencart 2.0.3.1 Email not send

Tags: php, email, opencart2.x

i'm install lexus golmart theme on opencart 2.0.3.1, Every thing is fine accept the order email & contact form, There is no error while ordering or submit contact form, but no email receive from both.

I do several changes like email address change, Mail protocol changes, SMTP values changes but no relife.

Please help me in this resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of searching I found a solution for this:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i;
```

Place this code in `php.ini` file in both root & admin files and all emails are alive now.

Answer (score 0):

Well make sure that

Store Email in 
  General tab 
    and 
  Mail tab

are then same and is xyz@yourdomian.com